# Select every day slot on jquery full calendar ver 2.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

the following code is a piece of the code generated by fullcalendrar jquery plugin ver 2. It has changed a bit since ver 1.x in the classes it uses.

```
<div class="fc-slats">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>07:00</span></td>
                <td class="fc-widget-content"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fc-minor">
                <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"></td>
                <td class="fc-widget-content"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fc-minor">
                <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"></td
                <td class="fc-widget-content"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fc-minor">
                <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"></td>             
                <td class="fc-widget-content"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"><span>08:00</span></td>
                <td class="fc-widget-content"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fc-minor">
               <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 37px;"></td>
               <td class="fc-widget-content"></td>
            </tr> <!--etc-->
        <tbody>
    <table>
</div>
```

I want to use jquery to select every second td(day slots) that is follow the follow path

```
.$("fc-slats > table tbody tr").children.eq(1)
```

Is the above jquery correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jquery isn't correct. You can use the following:

```
$(".fc-slats > table tbody tr").find("td:eq(1)")
```

Comment: when I do slots = $(".fc-slats > table tbody tr td:eq(1)").length returns 1...This is not right. Should return more since there are many slots (many more from my example)

Comment: it worked thank you..You should edit your answer and let me choose it as correct I think.