# Access jquery object when binding it using delegates

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27229923/2349589) I want it to find specific dom elements. The jquery selector using find provided in the solution was great. But I want to delegate this selector to bind it with "contextmenu" event. But it won't work if you pass jquery object in the delegate. What I do is the following.

```
var slots;
slots = $(".fc-slats > table tbody tr ").find("td:eq(1)");
$(".fc-agenda-view").on("contextmenu", slots, function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (paste===true) {
        showSlotContextualMenu($(this), e);
    }else{
        console.log($(this));
    }
});
```

I want $this object to be the slot but I read that I cannot use jquery object in "on" but I need to use a selector. What would be the equivalent selector for this?I want the td that is second child from the desired tr. Is it

```
.fc-slats > table tbody tr td:eq(1)
```

Comment: yes.... your selector seems to be correct

Comment: Didn't you try it before asking?

Comment: I did it didn't work it returned only one result. I had to use nth-child as bellow

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `on` should be a string selector to find the descendant elements of the primary selector. With that in mind, this should work:

```
$(".fc-agenda-view").on("contextmenu", '.fc-slats > table tbody tr td:eq(1)', function(e) {
    // your code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".fc-slats > table tbody tr > td:first-child", function (e){
     // .....
});
```

Comment: I uses this but used :nth-child(2) instead. That worked. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

What worked was the following.

```
var selector = ".fc-slats > table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)";
$(".fc-agenda-view").on("contextmenu",selector , function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (paste===true) {
        showSlotContextualMenu($(this), e);
   }else{
        console.log($(this));
   }
});
```